# How do I remove empty elements from the dom using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

The WordPress word editor spits out empty `<p>` tags like this: `<p>&nbsp;</p>`.

I would like to target all `<p>` with `&nbsp;` in them and remove them. I believe I have to use the `contains` and `remove` functions but I am not sure if this code would remove the `<p>` tags with only `&nbsp;` in them or remove all `<p>` tags with `&nbsp;` in them anywhere.

```
jQuery('p:contains("&nbsp;")').remove();
```

How would I make this work?

Comment: _The matching text can appear directly within the selected element, in any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof_

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter) and look if the innerHTML is equal to  :

```
$("p").filter(function(){
    return $.trim(this.innerHTML) === "&nbsp;"
}).remove();
```

Comment: @John. You could upvote the answer if it  _worked perfectly_! (the only upvote is mine...)