# If statement with Content block in October CMS

Tags: octobercms

In October CMS, I'm wondering if there is a way of checking if a content block is empty?

I am enclosing it in a message tag, which I would not wish to display if the block wasn't populated.

Something like:

```
{% if not empty content 'homepage/message' %}
      <div class="ui message positive home-messages">
          {% content 'homepage/message' %}
        </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your actual *question*
but it does, I believe, solve your problem.

My understanding is that you wish to remove the entire `<div>` block when it is empty, *ie* when the content block is empty.

Given the html/twig code of simply

```
<div class="ui message positive home-messages">
    {% content 'homepage/message' %}
</div>
```

This can be done with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( $.trim( $('div.message').text() ).length == 0 ) {
        $('div.message').remove();
    }
});
```

`$('div.message')` : Locate the `<div>` block with the 'message' class
`$('div.message').text()` : Take a copy of the enclosed *text* (removes all html tags)
`$.trim( $('div.message').text() )` : Trim off all whitespace including carriage returns and non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`)
`$.trim( $('div.message').text() ).length` : Measure the length of what's left
If it's zero, the `<div>` block is empty (no text or empty child html blocks), so
`$('div.message').remove();` : Remove the entire `<div>` block

*If you need to specify more than one class to avoid removing other empty div blocks with the `message` class, you can chain the classes,

eg `$('div.message.home-messages')`.*

You can save the jQuery code to `/themes/<theme>/assets/javascript/remove_empty.js`
and then inject it into the relevant page with

```
function onEnd() {
    $this->addJs('assets/javascript/remove_empty.js');
}
```

*You can instead add the `remove_empty.js` to the list of JavaScript assets at the bottom of the Layout file for use across the website. Injecting it, as above, means that it will only accompany that page.*

You could use the much simpler

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.message:empty').remove();
});
```

But this would require your html/twig to be all one line...

```
<div class="ui message positive home-messages">{% content 'homepage/message' %}</div>
```

...otherwise the `<div>` block will contain carriage returns (whitespace), and will therefore not be `:empty`.

See also:
* [Using an if statement to check if a div is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665466/using-an-if-statement-to-check-if-a-div-is-empty)
* [How do I remove empty elements from the dom using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656277/how-do-i-remove-empty-elements-from-the-dom-using-jquery)